# location.href doesn't get the real URL of Youtube, with livechat enabled in Chrome

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube get URL
// @namespace    example.com
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    alert(window.location.href);
}
```

Click one of VanossGaming's video including livechat for example https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKqH_9mk1waLgBiL2vT5b9g

**window.location.href** or **document.location.href** returns:
`https://www.youtube.com/live_chat_replay?continuation=op2w0wQuGiBDZzhhRFFvTExUaHpia0Z6U2pNMU4yc2dBUSUzRCUzREABYARyBAgEEAB4AQ%253D%253D`

---

The userscript only executes 1 time. I tried ViolentMonkey & TamperMonkey Beta, no luck.

---

Edit:
I found that it only runs for the livechaat iframe, but not for the main window. Second, if I manually F5 refresh the page instead click into the page from somewhere else, it works for the main window. Why wouldn't userscript run if I clicked into this video?

Comment: Your userscript also runs inside iframes. Either add `// @noframes` or check if (window === top)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the tip. I found that it only runs inside livechat iframes. That's weird, it doesn't run for the main window... I can do nothing with the main window's objects.

Comment: It does run there but just one time at the start because YouTube is a **SPA** site. See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) from which you can use the content script part (you may need to use a different yt-navigate event for your case though).

Comment: @wOxxOm This is exactly what I need! Thank you for the professional answer.